# Is there a way to pull "tr data-index" element for web-scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am very new to this and trying to scrape a webpage with following structure:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
    #rowelements
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1">
    #rowelements
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="2">
    #rowelements
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I try to extract the respective row elements in python using the following command I get [] as the output. How do I extract the row elements in this case? Thank you!

```
row=tbody.findAll("tr",{"data-index":"0"})
print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even `tbody.findAll("tr",{"data-index":"0"})` returns at least the first row:

```py
>>> tbody.findAll("tr", {"data-index":"0"})
[<tr data-index="0">
    #rowelements
    </tr>]
```

If you're not getting even 1 result, then your `tbody` doesn't contain what you've shown above. Try `print(tbody)` to check that.

Anyway, to get all the rows, use `tbody.findAll("tr", {"data-index": True})`:

```py
>>> tbody.findAll("tr", {"data-index": True})
[<tr data-index="0">
    #rowelements
    </tr>, <tr data-index="1">
    #rowelements
    </tr>, <tr data-index="2">
    #rowelements
    </tr>]
>>> len(_)
3
```